Any discussion of the zemer Bar Yohai Nimshahtah in the context of doresh el ha-methim?
Some sources (as discussed in this question) discourage directly addressing the deceased as bordering on the prohibition of דורש אל המתים (inquiring of/communicating with the dead Deut. 18:10-11). I am curious to know if there are any sources that discuss the zemer Bar Yohai Nimshahta in this context.
Throughout this zemer, R. Shim'on bar Yohai is directly addressed throughout (though he is not petitioned). If anyone is aware of any sources that discuss the zemer within the context of this prohibition please share it below. Thank you.

https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.1.26  My instinct is in contexts like this it's a rhetorical flourish and nobody actually thinks the deceased person is listening.

Similar questions regarding Eliyahu Hanavi come to mind. https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4763826/jewish/Why-Sing-About-Elijah-After-Shabbat.htm

@Heshy oof! Pretty strong precedent to contend with there!

@RabbiKaii similar, but I don't recall Eliyahu being directly addressed at all in it, it's more about him than to him... unless I'm misremembering a stanza (I'm not accustomed to reciting it anymore)

@Shababnik great resource on the larger topic of doresh el ha-methim, thanks for sharing!

@Deuteronomy indeed, there might also be some avenues that lead back to your question, if one looks at discussions surrounding cos shel Eliyahu?

@RabbiKaii round these parts we just call it kos hamishi ;)

https://yhb.org.il/shiurim/%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%91-%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A9-%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D/

Also https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sotah.5.2

While I'm not entirely sure where you see that we are praying to him. Can you point that out. See related: Teshuvot Maharam Shik (O.C. 293) who says that one can pray to a tzaddik to pray on one's behalf. See also Rav Pe'alim (vol. 2, Y.D. 31), BeTzel HaChochma (5:165), Minchat Elazar (1:68), Igrot Moshe (O.C. vol. 5, 43:6), Minchat Yitzchak (8:53), Chazon Ovadia (Avelut, vol. 3, p. 210).

@Shababnik he didn't say that we are praying to him (see second paragraph "though he is not petitioned").

@Shababnik as Harel13 notes, I didn't say that he is prayed to in the zemer - merely that he is directly addressed. As to your sources that might suggest one can "pray to a tzaddik to pray on one's behalf" there is clearly another side that maintains that such is improper. I am not looking to debate the issue, simply to know if anyone discusses it within the context of this zemer. Nevertheless, thank you for sharing those sources.

As I see it, the zemer is praises about Rashbi, we are not addressing him. 
I do recall hearing in the name of Rabbi Soleveichik that he didn't understand how we can call him "bar yochai" without a proper title. But other than that, I'm not sure of any problem. It was written by a very big mekubal and talmid chacham, and is praised by many tzaddikim as being a very lofty song that has many kabbalistic concepts hidden within it.

@Shababnik I think it is undeniable that the language is written in a form of direct address. I appreciate that this is your perspective, but as I said, I am looking for sources that discuss this aspect of the zemer (whether critical or in support of). If no such source exists, that's OK... it'll simply remain an open/unanswered question. All the best.

@Deuteronomy I do apologize. I was simply trying for something to write instead of ignoring. Though I see now that c was a mistake. Best wishes.
